# Am I using nHIbernate's ITransaction properly here?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, transactions

I'm just learning nHibernate and have come across what probably is a simple issue to resolve.

Right so I've figured out so far that you can't/shouldn;t nest nHibernate Transactions within each other; in my case I figured this out when scope went to another routine and I started a new Transaction.

So should I be doing the following?

```
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    NHibernateMembership mQuery =
        session.QueryOver<NHibernateMembership>()
            .Where(x => x.Username == username)
            .And(x => x.ApplicationName == ApplicationName)
            .SingleOrDefault();

    if (mQuery != null)
    {
        mQuery.PasswordQuestion = newPwdQuestion;
        mQuery.PasswordAnswer = EncodePassword(newPwdAnswer);
        session.Update(mQuery);

        transaction.Commit();
        passwordQuestionUpdated = true;
    }
}

// Assume this is in another routine elsewhere but being
// called right after the first in the same request
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    NHibernateMembership mQuery =
        session.QueryOver<NHibernateMembership>()
            .Where(x => x.Username == username)
            .And(x => x.ApplicationName == ApplicationName)
            .SingleOrDefault();

    if (mQuery != null)
    {
        mQuery.PasswordQuestion = newPwdQuestion;
        mQuery.PasswordAnswer = EncodePassword(newPwdAnswer);
        session.Update(mQuery);

        transaction.Commit();
        passwordQuestionUpdated = true;
    }
}
```

Note: I know they are simply a copy, i'm just demonstrating my question

**First Question** 
Is this the way it is MEANT to be done? Transaction per operation?

**Second Question** 
Do I need call transaction.Commit(); each time or only in the last set?

**Third  Question** 
Is there a better way, automated or manual, to do this?

**Third Question** 
Can I use session.Transaction.IsActive to determine if the "Current Session" already is part of a transaction - so in this case I can make the "Transaction wrap" in the highest level, let's say the Web Form code, and let routines be called within it and then commit all work at the end. Is this a flawed method?

I really want to hammer this down so I start as I mean to go on; I don;t want to find 1000s of lines of code in that I need to change it all.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Right so I wrote some code to explain my issue exactly.

```
private void CallingRoutine()
{
    using(ISession session = Helper.GetCurrentSession)
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            //  RUN nHIbernate QUERY to get an OBJECT-1

            //  DO WORK on OBJECT

            //  Need to CALL an EXTERNAL ROUTINE to finish work
            ExternalRoutine();

            //  DO WORK on OBJECT-1 again

            //  *** At this point ADO exception triggers
        }
    }
}

private bool ExternalRoutine()
{
    using(ISession session = Helper.GetCurrentSession)
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            //  RUN nHIbernate QUERY to get an OBJECT-2

            //  DO WORK on OBJECT

            //  Determine result
            if(Data)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this demonstrates the issue. This is how I understood to write the Transactions but notice how the ADO exception occurs. I'm obviously doing something wrong. How am I meant to write these routines?

Take for example if I was to write a helper object for some provider and within each routine exposed there is a nHibernate query run - how wold I write those routines, in regards to Transactions, assuming I knew nothing about the calling function and data - my job is to work with nHibernate effectively and efficiently and return a result.

This is what I assumed by writing the transaction how I did in ExternalRoutine() - to assume that this is the only use of nHibernate and to explicitly make the Transaction.

Comment: I don't believe you need the explicit call to session.Update in this example. Because these changes are made within a transaction scope, they will automatically be picked up and committed to the database with the call to transaction.Commit

Comment: That aside, even if I'm doing it for transparency - so if I come to read the code again I know exactly what is happening, that wasnt the focus of my question. It is more so the actual transaction itself and nesting. How should I write routines in class dlls for use with nhibernate. Think of it this way: let's say the calling routine is wrapped by a transaction, and I'm writing a function to interact with nHibernate, how would I write that function: absent a transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I would suggest using System.Transactions.TransactionScope:

```
using(var trans = new TransactionScope()) 
using(var session = .. create your session...) {
    ... do your stuff ...
    trans.Complete();
}
```

The trans.Complete will cause the session to flush and commit the transaction, in addition you can have nested transactionscopes.  The only "downside" to this is that it will escalate to DTC if you have multiple connections (or enlisted resources such as MSMQ), but this is not necessarily a downside unless you're using something like MySQL which doesn't play nicely with DTC.

For simple cases I would probably use a transaction scope in the BeginRequest and commit it in EndRequest if there were no errors (or use a filter if u're using ASP.NET MVC), but that really depends a lot on what you're doing - as long as your operations are short (which they should be in a web app), this should be fine.  The overhead of creating a session and transaction scope is not that big that it should cause problems for accessing static resources (or resources that don't need the session), unless you're looking at a really high volume / high performance website.

Comment: Right, like you said it doesn't play well with MySQL - in this case I have to use MySQL. I like the idea of opening the transaction at the "Start Request" and closing at "End Request" but don;t believe I can do this with MySQL. My thought process on transactions is that there should only really be one overall transaction in order to roll back all changes, but maybe I am wrong? Considering there is only one session, and multiple separate transactions within that one session, if any one of those transaction were to error, could they all be rolled back or just the one that error-ed?

Comment: To continue on my last comment, maybe my view of the Transaction is wrong? Like my example in the comment, is it ok to have multiple transactions within the same session? I ask because in my view, on Transactions, only the last transaction could be rolled back and not those before it in the same request. To be clear, which I am never good at, my overall question relates to the process of the overall session and how it can roll back if there are multiple transactions within.

Comment: Firstly, TransactionScope will still work with MySql as long as u're not opening more than 1 connection within the same transaction.  Secondly, it is technically ok to have multiple transactions in the same session like you've done, but I would recommend against it because if you rollback a transaction in the middle, then the session might become inconsistent, and if you commit a later transaction it might well commit the changes you thought you had rolled back.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if NHibernate will rollback the changes to your in memory entity if you rollback the transaction (I think it won't).

Comment: Ok, so now I'm completley confused. So what you are saying I shouldn't have more than one transaction in the same session request, even though they are after each of them close - as in transaction (A) runs to commit, then a new transaction (B) starts (after/outside) transaction (A) and commits etc and so on until request end. How am I meant to do it in that case? All the documentation I read suggest to explicitly surround work with a transaction but when I do this, and for instance a routine is called within a transaction (and that commits), I then get an ADO exception error in the first.

Comment: I updated my question with some code to hopefully explain my issue.

Comment: If you want to use nested transactions, your only option is TransactionScope (or roll your own).  I would also recommend having a 1-to-1 relationship between session and transaction if you're not using nested transactions.  So if you want multiple transactions and not nested transactions inside a request, then use multiple sessions (but I would question why you need multiple transactions inside 1 request in the first place)